# Fully transparent Bootstrap button but still active

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I'd like to make a button with the only visible text inside made with Font Awesome:

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</button>
```

I forced all the borders, background etc as transparent:

**CSS**

```
.btn {
    outline: none;
    border: 0px; 
    box-sizing: none; 
    background-color: transparent; 
 }
```

Well, works well unless I click on the button. Then the default blue Bootstrap  border shows. How to make all the button-like features make transparent but keep the text highlighting on hover event (changes to blue)? I have tried to add the `.btn:active` to CSS file, but not working.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1res9poq/). Resize horizontally.Click the button with bars on the right to see the blue border I need to dissapear.

Comment: This would be much easier if you made a fiddle

Comment: Change to this outline: none !important;

Comment: @BARNI I want to avoid the !important clause even it overrides the external file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll most likely need to be more specific with your rules since you're overriding Bootstrap classes. See [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

**Example CSS:**

```
.navbar .navbar-toggle,
.navbar .navbar-toggle:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
.navbar .navbar-header .navbar-toggle,
.navbar .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="menu">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="btn navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">A</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">B</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">C</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">D</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">E</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </nav>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```